# Не работает эмитер после перезагрузки страницы(socket.io, nodejs, Angular 6)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, angular

Столкнулся с данной проблемой:
когда клиентская часть подключается в первый раз эмит нормально работает. Но когда клиент перезагружает страницу (F5), никакие эмиты не работают.

Клиентская часть кода:

```
this.socket = io.connect(environment.backendChat);
...
this.socket.on('sendUsers', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
});
...
```

Серверная часть кода:

```
io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
            console.log('---USER CONNECTED---');
            console.log('CONNECT: ', socket.connected);
            console.log('DISCONNECT: ', socket.disconnected);
            console.log('--------------------');

            users.push(socket.id);
            console.log(users);

        app.get('/api/chat/chat-contacts', (req, res)=> {
            database.collection('userViewer').find({}).toArray((err, item)=> {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    emitFunction();
                    res.send(item);
                }
            });
        });

        function emitFunction() {
            console.log('function emit');
            socket.emit('sendUsers', users);
        }
```

При первом заходе на страницу в консоль выводится массив users. Но при перезагрузке страницы в консоле браузера ничего не выводится.

Comment: вы на каждый конекшн создаете новый хендлер `get('/api/chat/chat-contacts')`?

Comment: да. при первом коннекте все работает. после реконнекта(то есть при перезагрузки страницы) нет.

Comment: Нашел решение? Столкнулся с той же проблемой.

Comment: да нашел решение...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.socket.on('sendUsers', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

этот кусок кода нужно было перенести в `ngOnInit()`.